# Spring Integration with Amazon SQS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-integration, amazon-sqs

hopefully this is an easy question - has anyone had any luck using Spring Integration with Amazon SQS?  I've had a play with this project ...

https://github.com/3pillarlabs/spring-integration-aws

... but after a couple of hours all I was able to get is the following error: -

```
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'integration:channelAdapterType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

NOTE: I was using the following versions of Spring and Spring integration ...

```
<spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.integration.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
```

Any help / advice is massively appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you mind to try this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-aws ? Our official Spring Intgration Extension

Comment: I seen that project but I noticed the following "Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) (Development complete, coming soon)".  Do you have any examples of Spring Integration with SQS?

Comment: The latest version (1.1) uses Spring 3.1.2 & Spring Integration 2.1.4. I will be working shortly to update the dependencies to latest versions. Meanwhile, could you please add it to the issue tracker on Github, when you get a chance & assuming you still find the project interesting?! BTW, I am the author on this project.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, I have not yet played with this.  However, it's what I'll probably be porting some code to tomorrow.

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_sqs_support